# How to record listened key strokes as string?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-hook

I'm listening all key events by a global hook with `SetWindowsHookEx`. Lets assume a user types `a`, `b`, `c`, `BackSpace`, and `d`. This sequence results the string `abd`. Is there an easy way to convert a sequence of key strokes to the resulting string like in a text area?

I'm thinking about redirecting these strokes to a hidden text area with another PInvoke function `SetForegroundWindow` but it seems too tricky and probably slows down the system considerably.

What is the most simple way of doing this?

Comment: The user isn't typing a string, the user is typing characters, so `IEnumerable<char>` would be your best bet.

Comment: How would `IEnumerable<char>` help me in this situation? User is typing characters to construct a string!